# LDAPS Authentication for Nagios Web GUI

Tags: apache, ldap, openldap, nagios

I am trying to enable LDAPS authentication for my Nagios web GUI (https://localhost/nagios) against Active Directory. I've set this up with LDAP before without much trouble, but LDAPS is a headache.
I think my cert is valid since Event Viewer in Active Directory shows what I believe is a successful credential validation.
In my browser, after entering username and pwd for AD, it spins for a while and ends up at an Internal Server Error page.
None of my logs give me anything useful.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. nagios.conf - Modified for LDAPS (see below attached file)
2. ldap.conf - Added the following lines:

   > HOST "hostname"
   >   PORT 636
   >   TLS_CACERT /etc/httpd/conf.d/rootcert.pem
   >   TLS_REQCERT never
3. (FYI, rootcert.pem was created by taking the cert issued by the root CA and converting to pem format):

   > openssl x509 -inform der -in rootcert.cer -out rootcert.pem

Here is my nagios.conf. Stuff in [brackets] are edited to not include my real info:

> ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"
>
> <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
>   SSLRequireSSL
>   Options ExecCGI
>   AllowOverride None
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
>   AuthBasicProvider ldap
>   AuthType Basic
>   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
>   AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
>   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
>   AuthName "Active Directory Login 1"
>   AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://[myActiveDirServerName]:636/DC=[dc1],DC=[dc2],DC=[dc3],DC=[dc4]?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
>   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=nagiosadmin,OU=[ou1],OU=[ou2],OU=[ou3],DC=[dc1],DC=[dc2],DC=[dc3],dc=[dc4]"
>   AuthLDAPBindPassword [passwd]
>   Require valid-user
>   </Directory>
>
> Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"
>
> <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
>   SSLRequireSSL
>   Options ExecCGI
>   AllowOverride None
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
>   AuthBasicProvider ldap
>   AuthType Basic
>   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
>   AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
>   AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
>   AuthName "Active Directory Login 2"
>   AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://[myActiveDirServerName]:636/DC=[dc1],DC=[dc2],DC=[dc3],DC=[dc4]?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
>   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=nagiosadmin,OU=[ou1],OU=[ou2],OU=[ou3],DC=[dc1],DC=[dc2],DC=[dc3],dc=[dc4]"
>   AuthLDAPBindPassword [passwd]
>   Require valid-user
>   </Directory>

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

Switched port from 636 to 3269.

Also used a different cert. My host sits in a different network enclave than the AD server so I needed to chain together my PEM-converted intermediate and root certs:

> openssl x509 -inform der -in rootcert.cer -out rootcert.pem
>   openssl x509 -inform der -in intermediateCert.cer -out intermediateCert.pem
>   cat intermediateCert.pem rootcert.pem > chainedCert.pem
>   (Then use chainedCert.pem in ldap.conf. Youll need to change the permissions on that cert too)